# Error propagation from fit parameters

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, error, error-propagation

I have two distinct data samples($A$ and $B$), and to each one a gaussian is fitted. I then evaluate the product  $S = \sigma_A * \sigma_B$  ($\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ and their errors are obtained from fit procedure).

If I assume   $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ are uncorrelated, I can easily propagated the error on the product ($S$) based on the  estimates of $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ errors.

But what would be the correct way to propagate the error to include a possible correlation between  $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$?

Comment: Let me say that I don't know, but I can make an educated first guess. (Hopefully this might help / provide some food for thought until someone else can answer w/ the derivation you need; then I'll delete this comment). You would put the correlation matrix b/t the variables. That is, $S=\sigma_A*\Sigma_{\sigma_A,\sigma_B}*\sigma_B$. NB, that when the errors are uncorrelated, this will reduce the the equation you listed, as the correlation matrix will be the identity matrix.